# Changing form of ODE to bessel form

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$x\frac{d^2F}{dx}+\frac{dF}{dx}+\frac{w^2}{g}F$ can be written in the form of

$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx}+x\frac{dy}{dx}+(x^2-p^2)y$ by letting $z^2=\frac{4x}{g}$ and using they chain rule: $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dz}\frac{dz}{dx}$

Using these tools the original ODE should look like: $\frac{d^2F}{dz^2}+\frac{1}{z}\frac{dF}{dz}+w^2F=0$.

I found $\frac{dF}{dx}$ in terms of $\frac{dF}{dz}$ by $$\frac{dF}{dz}=\frac{\frac{dF}{dx}}{\frac{dz}{dx}}$$

so $$\frac{dF}{dx}=\frac{2}{gz}\frac{dF}{dz}$$

My question is how do I find $\frac{d^2F}{dx^2}$ in terms of $\frac{dF}{dz}$.

Comment: Use the chain rule and product rule.

Comment: Well, I don't know why you need it but you can apply chain rule again: $ {d^2 F \over dx^2} = {d \over dx} {d F \over dx}={{d  \over dz} {d F \over dx}   {dz \over dx}  } $. And, as you let $z^2={4x \over g } $, $2z{d z \over dx} ={4 \over g} $

Comment: where should I use the chain rule and product rule